# Rude comments embedded in user profiles

Tags: discussion, etiquette, policy, user-profile

I have a problem with a particular user's profile, specifically this line:

> See what's going on with my answers. They take the hints and ideas from my answers and then they down vote and delete them.

I feel that this is extremely rude to me and others who actually provided valid hints and solutions to that particular problem.

While I accept the possibility that I am just overreacting, I am wondering if there was a standard procedure for reporting profiles that one might find offensive or inappropriate.

Comment: The simplest way is to flag the answer that seems to have motivated this behavior for moderator attention. The moderators know who the problematic users are, and can decide on a course of action. Because we need a pattern of problematic behavior, the response will not be as swift as you might hope. I see that another moderator also has already visited the thread in question.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thank you for a prompt response. I will do that in the future. It seems like the answer itself has been removed.

Comment: Yes. The answer has been deleted. By regular users. The reason why I think flagging is often better is that then we avoid drawing attention to a specific user in meta. Such threads may become nasty. On other occasions (like plagiarism suspicions) moderators need help in collecting evidence to identify problematic behavior, so this is not always clear cut. Use your judgement.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I understand that one can flag answers or comments, but I take it there is no simple one-click way to flag profiles?

Comment: ["How to flag a user for a strange behavior"](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17087/how-to-flag-a-user-for-a-strange-behavior)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can try to flag a post by that user for moderator attention. At present (and likely far into the future) [there is no way to flag a user profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39334/214632).

But be aware that users have quite free reign on their user profiles. Sure, pornographic material, racist epithets, and other truly offensive material (*e.g.*, there was a recent spate of avatars with Nazi symbolism on, if I remember correctly, SO) will almost certainly be removed by moderators (if not done voluntarily), but simply being "rude" or "childish" is very likely not enough to warrant any direct moderator involvement.